# Extract desired information from a string in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Below is the string that I get, now I want to extract the two 3840 from this line, what command should I be using in Bash scripting?

> `Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x3840 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 100072 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe it into grep `grep -oE "[1-9][0-9]*x[1-9][0-9]*"` which would extract `3840x3840`.

Following is an example which retrieves both the width and height in separate variables:

```
INPUT="Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1024x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 100072 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc"
RES=`echo $INPUT | grep -oE "[1-9][0-9]*x[1-9][0-9]*"` # 1024x768
WIDTH=`echo $RES | cut -f1 -dx` # get the first column, where 'x' is the separator
HEIGHT=`echo $RES | cut -f2 -dx` # get the second column, where 'x' is the separator
echo $WIDTH # 1024 in this example
echo $HEIGHT # 768 in this example
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if the INPUT you have here actually comes from a .txt file? I tried to read the file in my script using cat but it doesn't work.

Comment: And btw I tried your solution, but WIDTH and HEIGHT don't equal to 1024 and 768 in this case, I got $RES | cut -f1 -dx and $RES | cut -f2 -dx instead, is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: No the code should work, I tried it within a shell script, I only added the comments afterwards -- I see there was a space missing for the height comment. If you want the content of a file you could do `cat my_file.txt | grep....`. In any case `echo $WIDTH` should not print the command but the result, since the [backticks](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash) above execute the command.

Answer (score 1):

Use cut with a pipeline:

```
newstring=`echo "<your string here>"|cut -f3 -d","`
```

Note the back-tics!  Your newstring should contain "3840x3840 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1]",  now you can do another cut and pipeline:

```
result=`echo $newstring|cut -f1 -d" "`
```

Or to put it all together:

```
result=`echo "<your string here>"|cut -f3 -d","|cut -f1 -d" "`
```

And you should now have "3840x3840".  All of this is pretty basic "cut" command along with pipes - check the manpage for these options and more for cut.

Comment: but if I have this string saved to a txt file first, then can I just do these operations upon the .txt file?

Comment: If it's in a txt file, then:
    result=`cat <filename>|cut -f3 -d","|cut -f1 -d" "`
Portable, works in systems that only have csh or ksh, or sh, not just bash.  Uses common *nix commands that will be on any *nix system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want NxM where N=M, you can use grep with back reference.

```
grep -Eo '([0-9]+)x\1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash rematch

```
val="Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x3840 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 100072 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn
, 119 .88 tbc"
[[ $val =~ ([0-9]{4})x([0-9]{4}) ]] 
         echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
         echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```